# Что такое raw socket и в чем его преимущество?

Tags: c++, сеть, сокет, winsock

пытаюсь учить сетевое программирование, но пока слабо получается. Если с TCP или UDP вопрос не возникает, то с raw не могу разобраться.

Comment: Что именно вызывает у Вас затруднения ?

Comment: А что конкретно не ясно?

Comment: @vegorov Что значит контролируя каждый бит заголовка и отправляя в сеть нестандартные пакеты, конкретнее, что такое нестандартный пакет?

Comment: @Croessmah Что значит контролируя каждый бит заголовка и отправляя в сеть нестандартные пакеты, конкретнее, что такое нестандартный пакет?

Comment: @rabblex вы можете самостоятельно формировать пакеты.

Comment: @rabblex для примера, на сырых сокетах можно построить сниффер.

Comment: @Croessmah то есть пакетом  может быть все что угодно?

Comment: @Croessmah А для чего нужен SOCK_SEQPACKET?

Comment: http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Sequenced_Packets_Over_Ordinary_TCP.html

Comment: Они (raw sockets) просто несколько другие, нежели привычные вам TCP/UDP. [A raw socket is used to receive raw packets. This means packets received at the Ethernet layer will directly pass to the raw socket. Stating it precisely, a raw socket bypasses the normal TCP/IP processing and sends the packets to the specific user application](https://opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/) / А [тут](https://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html) тоже полезные примеры